# ❤️Scrambled emoji tale☠️ #️1️⃣

Tags: visual, rebus, emoji

> Note: If the emoji characters of this question and its answers are borked, doubtful and what you can see are mostly boxes (like □ or �), you could try to install [this extension if you are using Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-swap-by-emojione/laaoconppkgneoeccdehhabfiojpekoa) or [this other one if you are using Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/emoji-everywhere/).
>
> I [took an screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcCqy.png) of the question below as it was rendered in my PC when I posted it (Chrome on Windows 10). Using the aforementioned extension for Chrome produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKOSe.png). Using the aforementioned extension for Firefox produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaNLo.png).

---

Here is a story. It has 22 parts that were scrambled (each part in one line).

‍

:️∃>❔

❕️→→⛰️⚡⏬☠️

❤️=

:‍

☀️⚒️

⏪❤️

:️∃>❔

:☠️

⚒️→

⛄:✂️❄️→✂️❤️→❄️

❄️

‍←❤️

☠️⚰️

→️→→️→→️️️

:️∃>❔:❤️

❤️:⏩

⏩→

⏩⚰️:️→

→☠️→⚰️

‍→❤️→

→:→→

**Can you unscramble it, describe what each step means and retell the story? What is the title? Can you list all the characters?**

Hints:

1. There is more than one possible order because there some steps that happens in parallel involving different characters in different places but at roughly the same time. Any reasonable sequence will do.
2. There are many different versions of this story around and they vary a lot. I tried to tell one that should be roughly what the most frequently told one is, although it might not be exactly that.

Comment: we don't want any more Emoji Movies... Don't give them the ideas! (nice puzzle though)

Comment: Is there an emoji to express the feeling of being unable to make sense of this riddle because your browser does not render most of the glyphs?

Comment: @Philipp Yeah, □

Comment: @Philipp That is the reason I added a link to a [**screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcCqy.png). I didn't added the actual image to the text (just the link) to avoid duplicating the content.

Comment: In which systems do all the symbols show properly? I've got a few missing ones in the body, the [question title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Neyol.png) and the [browser window title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atukW.png) :s

Comment: @user1306322 I used an updated Chrome in Windows 10. BTW, I'm thinking about bringing the emoji (in)compatibilities/differences issue to meta to seek some guidance for future challenges.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

⏪❤️

> Back in time, the king  was married to the queen

⛄:✂️❄️→✂️❤️→❄️

> In the winter ⛄, the queen  sits sewing ✂️ on a black (ebony?) windowsill , with snow outside ❄️ in the forest . She pricks her finger ✂️ and blood drips ❤️  on to the snow ❄️.

❄️

> The queen  wishes  for a baby  with skin as white as snow ❄️, lips as red as blood , and hair as black as ebony

☠️⚰️

> The queen  gives birth  (haha) to a baby , dies in childbirth ☠️⚰️, and the king is sad

❤️=

> The king  remarries and Snow White's new stepmother / is wicked

:️∃>❔

> The stepmother  asks ❔ the magic mirror ️ if there exists ∃ anyone fairer than her. It says no

⏩→

> Fast forward, Snow White  is grown up  now (and has become more beautiful)

:️∃>❔

> The stepmother  asks ❔ the magic mirror ️ if there exists ∃ anyone fairer than her. It says yes , Snow White

:☠️

> The stepmother is shocked  and angry , she plans  to have Snow white  killed ☠️

‍←❤️

> The stepmother  pays  a huntsman ‍ to kill Snow White and bring her her heart ❤️

‍

> The huntsman ‍ sees  Snow White , he takes pity on her  and tells her to run

‍→❤️→

> The huntsman ‍ kills  an animal  and gives it heart to the queen →❤️→ (does she eat it?? )

→️→→️→→️️️

> Snow White  is scared , befriends woodland creatures ... who lead her through the woods  to a messy house ️, which she tidies →️️️

⚒️→

> The 7 dwarves are mining ⚒️ in the mountains, get home  at night, see Snow White , they are shocked , decide to let her stay , (and sing a song or something? )

:️∃>❔:❤️

> The stepmother  asks ❔ the mirror ️ whether there exists ∃ anyone fairer than her >, and Snow White  is, because it was actually an animal's heart ❤️

:‍

> The stepmother  is angry the huntsman lied ‍

☀️⚒️

> In the daytime ☀️ the dwarves ... are away mining ⚒️ in the mountains

→:→→

> The stepmother  disguises herself as an old woman , poisons an apple , goes to visit  Snow White  who eats the apple , becomes ill  and falls into a deep sleep

❕️→→⛰️⚡⏬☠️

> The animals ... chase the stepmother  to the mountains where lightning ⚡ strikes the cliff and she falls ⏬ to her death ☠️

→☠️→⚰️

> The dwarves ... go home and think Snow White  is dead. They're upset . They bury her in a glass casket ⚰️ in the woods

⏩⚰️:️→

> Fast forward ⏩, the prince  sees  Snow White  in the glass casket ⚰️, kisses her , she wakes up and it's love at first sight . The dwarves and woodland creatures are thankful

❤️:⏩

> The prince marries  Snow White , they live happily ever after ⏩

---

I think the colon : is used for something specific. Maybe

> ["such that"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432345/such-that-logical-symbol), given that ∃ is also used

but it doesn't seem to fit

Comment: @VictorStafusa I've given it another go!

Comment: The colon has different meanings accordingly to the context. But it is not anything really special that would change things. It is really only punctuation.

Comment: The history is complete and correct, congratulations. BTW, I intended "⏪" to be "*Once upon a time*".

Comment: @VictorStafusa Thanks for the fun puzzle. :)

Comment: I particularly appreciated the use of different emoji to denote the names of the characters from the Disney version of the story.

Answer (score 21):

It looks to be

> Snow White and the Seven Dwarves

Some of the characters:

> : Snow White
>  : her stepmother, the evil queen
>  : the seven dwarves, Bashful, Doc, Grumpy, Dopey, Sleepy, Happy, Sneezy (not entirely sure of the order)
>  ‍: the huntsman / prince

Comment: Darn, that was too quick! However you still didn't decoded/unscrambled the parts.

Comment: Yeah, it will take some time to write that all out, time which I currently don't have (and there's probably already someone doing it right now). Let's all share in the fun!