# Scrambled emoji tale❤️⭐ #️3️⃣

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, emoji

## Today is July, 17th - [World Emoji Day](https://worldemojiday.com/)

So, today is time to post a new scrambled emoji tale.

This is the emoji tale#️3️⃣. Click [**here**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/65940/5044) and [**here**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86306/5044) to see the previous two.

Since my previous emoji tales were solved too quickly , I tried to make this one much harder .

There is a story  that was sliced ✂️ in a number of parts, one per line . Also, some parts are there just to serve as building blocks  of other parts. And some (actually almost all) parts of this repeats several times ! Further, to make this more harder there is a line that actually is part of some other very different story .

Differently than the previous puzzles, I didn't just ordered the lines randomly . Now I'm ordering them in crescent order accordingly to their size in Chrome's rendered emojis on Windows 10 using SE's MathJax. THIS IS SURELY THE BEST STRING SORTING ALGORITHM EVER INVENTED!

So, here it is:

---

$$10O; \aleph$$

$$\triangle \text{ is ...}$$

$$\require{cancel}\oplus \text{ is it ...}$$

$$\otimes \text{ is when ...}$$

$$\beth = \cancel{☝️}$$

$$\aleph =  \in A $$

$$q(x) = as + x + as$$

$$\overset{}{}️\oplus↔️:\overset{♀️}{}$$

$$k(z) = a(☝️❤️, 3❤️, z)$$

$$a(x, y, z) = x + z \times (y + x)$$

$$f(Something) = \bbox[blue]{Som} eth \bbox[red]{ing}$$

$$️\oplusMA\cancel{}\overset{♀️}{}$$

$$2\times\left(\frac{️}{}\right)\overset{♂️}{}\frac{️}{}$$

$$2\rlap{_{\cancel{\,\,}\,|}}️; 3A; \frac{5i(️)}{2}; ⭐f(); ☝️$$

$$☝️❤️\land ☝️; ☝️❤️; \beth$$

$$5O; \beth; \aleph; \beth; 5O; ☝️; \aleph; ☝️$$

$$f(☝️❤️\land ☝️; ☝️❤️); \beth$$

$$i(Some\,other\,thing) = \bbox[lime]{Some}\,other\,\bbox[red]{thing}$$

$$☝️❤️\land ☝️  \land ❄️✍️A$$

$$(☝️)\times(\cancel{}; ; ); q() \oplus \triangle \cancel{}; k(1)$$

$$4O; ☝️❤️\land \forall ❤️ \triangle   \land ❄️✍️A$$

$$☝️; ┃; ☝️ \in ⬜ \otimes  \triangle ; k(2)$$

$$☝️; ☝️ \begin{matrix} \rlap{\color{white}{D}}{}\\[-3ex] ║ \end{matrix}; \to RA q()R; k(1) $$

$$:☝️ \land :(NFS-FS); ☝️$$

$$☝️; T \rlap{}{\color{red}{\;\;\;◎}} \cancel{} ✋; ☝️\frac{}{}\in T(️-); \land k(2)$$

$$:☝️ \to M \cancel{} \overset{♀️}{}; \land :(NFS-FS); ☝️$$

---

Here are the questions:

> Q1.  Can you unscramble that, describe what each step means and retell the story?

> Q2.  Which line is part of some other story?

> Q3. $\mathfrak{T}$ What are the titles of the stories?

> Q4. ✋ Which emojis are the titles?

> Q5.  Can you tell who is the main character?

> Q6.  Can you tell which two consecutive emojis represent that main character?  Yes, two consecutive emojis, not only one, search carefully, they are right here !

Hints:

> H1.  Beware the homophones!

> H2.  A lot of people actually misunderstand about Alfred and think it is NSFW . If you see that, you got it wrong; pay attention closer!

> H3.  The first person is in the left.

> H4.  How and why do you call the waiter in a very noisy bar without leaving your seat?

> H5. ❤️ If it is neither left nor right, it should be down.

> H6. ❌ No, this has nothing to do with Disney, so the answer you look for is not an animal.

> H7. ️ If the emojis in your screen are borked, doubtful, glitched, and what you can see are mostly boxes (like □ or �), I took a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRMQ0.png) for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Q1. Below, as it is super lengthy.

Q2. The following line is part of another story:

> $2\times\left(\frac{️}{}\right)\overset{♂️}{}\frac{️}{}$
>  Can't read my, can't read my; No, he can't read my poker face
>  ***from OP:** According to H5, since the first person "I" is left and the second person "you" is right, the third person ("it" as in the hint or "he" as indicated by the male symbol) should be down*

Q3 & Q4. The titles of the stories (and their corresponding emojis) are...

> ... Bad Romance () and Poker Face ()

Q5 & Q6. The main character (and their corresponding emojis) is...

> ... Lady Gaga (⭐; emojis from the title of the question), the singer of these two songs (**from OP:** not to be confused with [Lady from *Lady and the Tramp*](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Lady) as per H6)!

---

Here are the definitions, roughly in the order they appear in the story:

$\aleph =  \in A $

> Caught in a bad romance

$a(x, y, z) = x + z \times (y + x)$
$k(z) = a(☝️❤️, 3❤️, z)$

> I want your love, [love, love, love; I want your love] with the part in [] repeated $z$ times

$f(Something) = \bbox[blue]{Som} eth \bbox[red]{ing}$
$i(Some\,other\,thing) = \bbox[lime]{Some}\,other\,\bbox[red]{thing}$

> These translate their arguments to the French or Italian versions (the letters "f" and "i" help confirm this)

$q(x) = as + x + as$

> Wraps its argument in "as" eg. $q()$ = "as long as"

$\require{cancel}\oplus \text{ is it ...}$
$\triangle \text{ is ...}$
$\otimes \text{ is when ...}$

> $\require{cancel}\oplus$ = "it", $\triangle$ = "is" or "are", $\otimes$ = "when"

$\beth = \cancel{☝️}$

> I don't wanna be friends

And one of my own that I think is helpful: ☝️

> "I want your"; this comes from H3 "The first person is in the left." (ie. "I" is represented by the left point) and H4 "How and why do you call the waiter in a very noisy bar without leaving your seat?" (ie. you put your finger up if you want something). "Your" is just the opposite of H3

The story goes as follows (since this is a crazy amount of work and for the sake of brevity, I'm not going to include repeated lines):
$10O; \aleph$

> Oh-oh-oh-oh-oooh; Oh-oh-oh-oh-oooh, oh-oh-oh; Caught in a bad romance

$2\rlap{_{\cancel{\,\,}\,|}}️; 3A; \frac{5i(️)}{2}; ⭐f(); ☝️$

> Rah, rah-ah-ah-ah; Roma, roma-ma; Gaga, ooh-la-la; Want your bad romance
>  Rome (️) in Italian is Roma, multiplying by five gives "roma roma roma roma roma", and taking (a very specific) half of this string yields "roma roma ma"
>  ***from OP:** ⭐ = Gaga because she was in* [A Star is Born](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Star_Is_Born_(2018_film))

$(☝️)\times(\cancel{}; ; ); q() \oplus \triangle \cancel{}; k(1)$

> I want your ugly, I want your disease; I want your everything as long as it's free; I want your love, love, love, love; I want your love

$☝️; T \rlap{}{\color{red}{\;\;\;◎}} \cancel{} ✋; ☝️\frac{}{}\in T(️-); \land k(2)$

> I want your drama, the touch of your hand; I want your leather-studded kiss in the sand; I want your love, love, love, love; I want your love (love, love, love, I want your love)
>  *I'm a little unsure about "leather-studded", but the jacket could be made of leather and a [stud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stud_(animal)) can be an animal for breeding, like an ox*

$:☝️ \land :(NFS-FS); ☝️$

> You know that I want you; And you know that I need you; I want it bad, your bad romance
>  *"NFS" stands for "[Need for Speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_Speed)"*

$☝️❤️\land ☝️  \land ❄️✍️A$
$4O; ☝️❤️\land \forall ❤️ \triangle   \land ❄️✍️A$

> I want your love, and I want your revenge; You and me could write a bad romance
>  I want your love and all your lover's revenge; You and me could write a bad romance
>  *I went with the lyrics Google gave me, but there are some "oh"s in the background in the song; I'm not going to track the "oh"s super carefully throughout*

$☝️; ☝️ \begin{matrix} \rlap{\color{white}{D}}{}\\[-3ex] ║ \end{matrix}; \to RA q()R; k(1) $

> I want your horror, I want your design; 'Cause you're a criminal as long as you're mine; I want your love, love, love, love; I want your love

$☝️; ┃; ☝️ \in ⬜ \otimes  \triangle ; k(2)$

> I want your psycho, your vertigo shtick; Want you in my rear window, baby, you're sick; I want your love, love, love, love; I want your love (love, love, love, I want your love)
>  ***from OP:** H2 applies here; [Alfred Hitchcock directed both Psycho and Vertigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Hitchcock#Films), and "vertigo shtick" could be misheard as "vertical stick", which could be seen as NSFW*

$:☝️ \to M \cancel{} \overset{♀️}{}; \land :(NFS-FS); ☝️$

> You know that I want you; And you know that I need you ('cause I'm a free b*tch, baby); I want it bad, your bad romance

$\overset{}{}️\oplus↔️:\overset{♀️}{}$
$️\oplusMA\cancel{}\overset{♀️}{}$

> Walk, walk, fashion baby; Work it, move that b*tch crazy
>  Walk, walk, passion baby; Work it, I'm a free b*tch, baby

$☝️❤️\land ☝️; ☝️❤️; \beth$
$f(☝️❤️\land ☝️; ☝️❤️); \beth$

> I want your love, and I want your revenge; I want your love, I don't wanna be friends
>  J'veux ton amour, et je veux ta revanche; J'veux ton amour, I don't wanna be friends

$5O; \beth; \aleph; \beth; 5O; ☝️; \aleph; ☝️$

> No, I don't wanna be friends (caught in a bad romance); I don't wanna be friends, want your bad romance; Caught in a bad romance; Want your bad romance

Comment: ROT13 - u2 vf orpnhfr n ybg bs crbcyr urne nf "iregvpny fgvpx" vafgrnq bs "iregvtb fugvpx" naq fbzrbar zvtug synt gur dhrfgvba qhr gb guvf. u5 vf orpnhfr "ur" vf arvgure yrsg abe evtug, vg vf qbja, hfrq gb shyyl qrpbqr cbxre snpr. u6 vf orpnhfr ynql tntn vf abg gur qbt vs fbzrbar gevrf gb znxr n pbaarpgvba gb na byq qvfarl pnegbba. Lbhe rkcynangvba ynpxf whfg n ovg va gur 5v/2 naq va gur yrngure-fghqqrq cnegf, ohg nalbar fb sne jbhyq znqr gur pbaarpgvba. Svanyyl, jul gur fgne? Orpnhfr N FGNE VF OBEA.

Comment: Congratulations! You very much nailed it! Have a green mark. PS: I need to find a way to make those puzzles harder...

Comment: @VictorStafusa Thanks! I'm still a little unsure about the parsing of rot13(yrngure-fghqqrq) but I added the rest of your comment. I think the difficulty of these puzzles lies more in the source material and how it's encoded as opposed to the length of the source material; my "in" for this puzzle was the value for $\aleph$, which was a pretty small piece of the puzzle, but once I cracked that, everything else fell into place. Hope that's at least a little helpful; great puzzle!

Comment: ROT13 - Gur qbt - Ynql naq gur Genzc

Comment: ROT13 - yrngure-fghqqrq vf bx

Comment: @VictorStafusa That makes more sense; I was looking for rot13(n Qvfarl punenpgre anzrq "Ynql Tntn"; "Ynql" pnzr hc va zl frnepu, ohg V qvqa'g znxr gur pbaarpgvba gung gung jnf jub uvag fvk jnf nobhg) XD